# Multiple Links Inside Same Google Sheet Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cells that have multi-line of text including multiple hrefs that I'd like to turn into clickable links. I can "format" the cell by clicking on the text of the href and clicking on another cell. How do I do this in a scalable way for all cells?

```
https://google.com
https://yahoo.com
text line
another text line
```

I want to turn google and yahoo into clickable links.

I've tried to replace `https://` with `=HYPERLINK("` and `.com` with `")` but gave me formula error.

I've tried these suggestions but they didn't work: [How to convert non-clickable links into clickable in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97285/how-to-convert-non-clickable-links-into-clickable-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Sorry, you cannot. Just manually. Or you would need to split the cells.